# html image will not load on web page

Tags: html

I am having difficulty getting my html image to appear on my web page. My image is in a file folder called images. I am practicing on jsfiddle and notepad and I cant' get the image to appear on either of them. My photo is in an file folder called images. I have  tried using  and it doesn't work. What step am I missing?

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: People cannot help you unless you put a link to the jsfiddle

Comment: please show us the code. we will be happy to assist

Comment: the code is <img src="C:\Users\Owner\Pictures\Saved Pictures\crystal-ball-photography-3894871_640.jpg">

Comment: Due to security restrictions, your browser cannot access you local files directly. That's why it will not work in jsfiddle. It may work if you open the html file as a local file too.